# DeleteCases messing with my mind

Tags: list-manipulation, numerics

I'm losing my mind. Please tell me my laptop is doing weird things and not me. Or do I need to get committed someplace?

```
data = {{872.2528741960809`, 2.7221624644873685`, 
0.02`}, {870.8866903801253`, 0.25288222647045855`, 
0.0201`}, {869.5228595650024`, 0.2668660821332401`, 0.0202`}}

Table[boundary0[H1R] = DeleteCases[data, a_ /; a[[1]] <= H1R || a[[2]] >= H1R], {H1R, 0.1,
0.9, 0.1}];
```

This should collect sets where the first and the second entry of each row are on either side of the index of the set.

When I input

```
boundary0[0.6]
```

I get

```
 {{870.887, 0.252882, 0.0201}, {869.523, 0.266866, 0.0202}}
```

but when I input

```
boundary0[0.7]
```

I get no output.., just my command is repeated

```
boundary0[0.7]
```

When I enter

```
boundary0[0.8]
```

I get

```
 {{870.887, 0.252882, 0.0201}, {869.523, 0.266866, 0.0202}}
```

So back to normal.

Now when I do

```
Table[boundary0[H1R] = DeleteCases[data, a_ /; a[[1]] <= H1R || a[[2]] >= H1R], {H1R,0.7, 0.9, 0.1}];
```

and then I do

```
 boundary0[0.7]
```

voila.. I get

```
{{870.887, 0.252882, 0.0201}, {869.523, 0.266866, 0.0202}}
```

Is my laptop the son of anti-christ? Is it gas-lighting me? Do I need to drive a stake through my kernel?

Comment: It's rounding error; `boundary0[0.7000000000000001]` is defined, but `boundary0[0.7]` is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a floating point issue. The article ["What every computer scientist should know about floating point arithmetic"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.6768) by David Goldberg, is a very good introduction to the topic.

In your case, look at the following:

```
Table[NumberForm[i, 16], {i, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1}] // TableForm
(*  0.1
    0.2
    0.3
    0.4
    0.5
    0.6
    0.7000000000000001
    0.8
    0.9 *)
```

The `DownValue` is defined for `0.7000000000000001`, not `0.7`. On the other hand, look at this:

```
Table[NumberForm[i, 16], {i, 0.7, 0.9, 0.1}] // TableForm
(*  0.7
    0.7999999999999999
    0.9 *)
```

Comment: Your computer fares a bit better than mine; here's how the sequence looks on my end: `0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6000000000000001, 
0.7000000000000001, 0.8, 0.9`

Comment: In my machine both `.6`and `.7`show this behavior. However `boundary0[.6]` is  "defined" while `boundary0[.7]` isn't

Comment: @rm-rf.. thank goodness I'm not the one losing it. So is there a way to get around this?

Comment: @Amatya: easy, use rationals instead of reals (i.e., define `boundary0[1/10]`, ... `boundary0[9/10]` instead).

Comment: @J.M. oh sweet... thank you!

Comment: Er…can this be concluded as: we should avoid using a real number for the step size of loops and recursions?