# Removing zero values from ordered pairs

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have some processed data, which are basically a collection of ordered pairs in the form:

```
{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ..., {xn, yn}}
```

Ordered pairs which have either a zero $x$ or $y$ component are not physically meaningful, and should be deleted from the data. I can't for the life of me figure out how to delete these points. I've tried `DeleteCases`, `Position`, `Select`, `Cases`, etc. and none of them work for my application.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(14122)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14122/121), [(15907)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15907/121) and related: [(5149)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5149/121), [(6994)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6994/121)

Answer (score 5):

The best choice is an appropriate use of `DeleteCases`. 
I'd recommend `DeleteCases` with a pattern `{___, 0,___}` (see `BlankNullSequence`) since it can remove zeros in more general lists than of those of length `2`, moreover it is resonably faster than `{a_, 0} | {0, a_}`, on the other hand it is slower than `{_, 0} | { 0, _}`. One can use also `{___, 0 | 0., ___}` in any case.  Let's demonstrate  two cases :

```
list1 = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {10^5, 2}];
list3 = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {10^6, 2}];


DeleteCases[list3, {a_, 0} | {0, a_}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
DeleteCases[list3, {_, 0} | {0, _}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
DeleteCases[list3, {___, 0, ___}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.203125
> 0.156250
> 0.171875
> ```

```
DeleteCases[list3, {a_, 0} | {0, a_}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
DeleteCases[list3, {_, 0} | {0, _}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
DeleteCases[list3, {___, 0, ___}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 2.000000
> 1.609375
> 1.765625
> ```

Comment: Well, not really. The fastest seems to be `DeleteCases[list, {_, 0} | {0, _}]`.

Comment: Where are your tests ? Have you done them ? I've tried more lists and  `{___, 0, ___}` has been faster than `{a_, 0} | {0, a_}` everytime.

Comment: ok, I added  another case `{_, 0} | { 0, _}` but one can delete `0` in much longer lists with `{___, 0, ___}`

Comment: I've added a snapshot to my answer. It seems that `{_, 0} | {0, _}` and  `{a_, 0} | {0, a_}` are different…

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to handle exact **and numeric** 0 too! The pattern matcher in any case where the zero is specified as the integer `0` (like in `Select[list, FreeQ[#, 0] &]`) **won't recognize a numerical zero**, as `0 =!= 0.0`.

```
list = {{1, 1}, {2, 0.}, {0, 4}, {0, 0.}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}, {1, 0.}, {0, 3}};

list /. {___, 0 | 0., ___} :> Sequence[]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}}
> ```

For even more robustness:

```
list /. {___, _?PossibleZeroQ, ___} :> Sequence[]
```

or for testing numerical value (possible other than zero), use Equal explicitly:

```
list /. {___, _?(# == 0. &), ___} :> Sequence[]
```

This is necessary as matching with `Replace` uses `MatchQ` which tests pattern identity and therefore misses equal numerical values:

```
0. /. {0 -> True, 0. -> False}                       (* ==> False *)
{MatchQ[0., 0], MatchQ[0.0000000000000000000, 0.]}   (* ==> {False, False} *)
{SameQ[0., 0], SameQ[0.0000000000000000000, 0.]}     (* ==> {False, True} *)
{Equal[0., 0], Equal[0.0000000000000000000, 0.]}     (* ==> {True, True} *)
{PossibleZeroQ@0, PossibleZeroQ@0., PossibleZeroQ@0.0000000000000000000}
                                                     (* ==> {True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: OK, I forgot it completly ORZ…

Comment: I actually remembered this after I posted my answer but was too lazy to incorporate it. Nice one.

Comment: For robustness you should be using `Equal`.  Some values that you would want to match do not: `MatchQ[0.0000000000000000000, 0 | 0.]`.

Comment: @Mr.W True that, thanks.

Comment: @Mr.W Please see edit. I wonder why `MatchQ[0.0000000000000000000, 0.]` does not fall back to use `SameQ`. What exactly `MatchQ` uses if it is not `SameQ` in such cases?

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly `SameQ` makes slight adjustments for bit rounding.  You can set the threshold with ``Internal`$SameQTolerance``.  Pattern matching (`Replace`, `Cases`, etc) does not actually use `SameQ`.  Incidentally, I find `x_ /; x == 0` cleaner than `_?(# == 0. &)`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Just a sidenote: I'm not sure `Equal` is the best case for zero-testing, as it does not return a boolean for nonnumeric input. Therefore `Equal` could pose a problem when e.g. picking out nontrivial solutions of `Solve`, e.g. `Cases[{x -> 0, x -> k - h/r}, _?(Last@# != 0 &)]` vs. `Cases[{x -> 0, x -> k - h/r}, _?(Not@PossibleZeroQ@Last@# &)]`.

Comment: @István I'm well aware of that behavior, but it's only a problem in inverted cases like you show.  You could add `TrueQ` or write: `DeleteCases[{x -> 0, x -> k - h/r}, _?(Last@# == 0 &)]`.  Of course `PossibleZeroQ`, `SameQ` etc. all have a place as well.  It really depends on the behavior you want.  I'll stand by my statement that `Equal` is usually the the best choice.

Comment: For readability, I prefer `list /. {___, x_ /; x == 0, ___} :> Sequence[]`.

Answer (score 3):

`DeleteCases`, `Position`, `Select`, `Cases` all works:

```
list = {{1, 1}, {2, 0}, {0, 4}, {0, 0}};

DeleteCases[list, {a_, 0} | {0, a_}]
Extract[list, Position[list2, {a_ /; a != 0, b_ /; b != 0}]]
Select[list, #[[1]] != 0 && #[[2]] != 0 &]
Select[list, FreeQ[#, 0] &]
Select[list, ! MemberQ[#, 0] &]
Cases[list, Except[{_, 0} | {0, _}]]


(*
{{1,1}}
{{1,1}}
{{1,1}}
{{1,1}}
{{1,1}}
{{1,1}}
*)
```

---

Here's a speed test for the solutions given by RunnyKine, Artes and me:

[image]

---

OK, I had been completely forgot the `0.` before István Zachar mentioned it ORZ. For completeness:

```
list2 = {{1, 1}, {2, 0}, {0, 4}, {0, 0}, {0, 0.}, {0., 3}, {4, 0.}};

DeleteCases[list2, {a_, 0 | 0.} | {0 | 0., a_}]
Extract[list2, Position[list2, {a_ /; a != 0, b_ /; b != 0}]]
Select[list2, #[[1]] != 0 && #[[2]] != 0 &]
Select[list2, FreeQ[#, 0 | 0.] &]
Select[list2, ! MemberQ[#, 0 | 0.] &]
Cases[list2, Except[{_, 0 | 0.} | {0 | 0., _}]]

(*
{{1,1}}
{{1,1}}
{{1,1}}
{{1,1}}
{{1,1}}
{{1,1}}
*)
```

Notice that the modification of the code is only necessary for the pattern match, so my second and third solutions with `Unequal`(`!=`) are not changed.

Answer (score 3):

This is not general, but because you are removing *zeros*, you can use tricks like this:

```
Pick[list, Unitize[Times @@ Transpose @ list], 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way, @xzczd covered most of them.

```
list = {{1, 1}, {2, 0}, {0, 4}, {0, 0}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}, {1, 0}, {0, 3}};

list /. {x_, 0} -> Sequence[] /. {0, y_} -> Sequence[]
```

OR you could just do

```
list /. ({x_, 0} | {0, y_}) -> Sequence[]
```

AND for completeness as suggested by @Istvan

```
list /. ({x_, 0 | 0.} | {0 | 0., y_}) -> Sequence[]
```

gives:

```
{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

Answer (score -1):

list = {A,B,C,D,E,F}. Using DeleteCases[list, A|C|E] returns {B,D,F}. Also note that "0" is not the same as "0."

Comment: I believe that the OP wishes to delete ordered pairs, not individual elements.